# Name new file from variable

Tags: ruby

I've got a variable, the contents of which vary as the program progresses. 
I need a txt file created, pulling its name from the variable (whatever it happens to hold at the time).

I can't seem to do this.

Currently my code is

```
 $var="filename"
    f = File.open ("#$var.txt")
```

Other permutations of 'File.' fail to read the variable contents, just naming the file literally as '$var.txt'. Meanwhile with File.open, I get a 'No such file or directory' error. So I tried

```
$var="filename"    
   f = File.open ("#$var.txt", "w")
```

And the error is gone, but replaced with

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

***Okay so as soon as I finished this, I fixed the thing just by setting w+ outside the parentheses. Seems obvious in hindsight but I guess my question now is why every blasted piece of documentation anywhere gave me the wrong syntax...**

Comment: Please, show us which *exact* piece of documentation told you to put a space in between the message name and the argument list, so that we can warn other people about it, because that is, indeed, awful.

Comment: "Meanwhile with File.open, I get a 'No such file or directory' error." – Please, be more specific. The error message should contain the name of the file it couldn't find. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the opening and closing parenthesis next to the method call:

```
f = File.open("#{$var}.txt", "w")
```

Rather than this:

```
f = File.open ("#{$var}.txt", "w")
```

Remember that () has high operator precedence level and could be used to evaluate an expression and then try to pass the result to the method open.